# how to display multi level menu using ListViews

Tags: react-native

I have a set of multilevel data to be display using abovementioned component. Usually in `PHP` I simply iterate the data to display it as `li` but coming from web background, I just can't put it all together when using `react-native`. What is the right way to display a set of menu

FYI, I'm also using `react-native-router-flux` to manage the router.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build you own menu, you'll have to customize the `renderRow` of your `ListView`. If you take a look at RN's official doc on ListView [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html), it shows that you can specify a sectionID, for example.
You can then specify how each row renders.

> renderRow: function (rowData, sectionID, rowID, highlightRow) => renderable
>
> Takes a data entry from the data source and its ids and should return
>   a renderable component to be rendered as the row. By default the data
>   is exactly what was put into the data source, but it's also possible
>   to provide custom extractors. ListView can be notified when a row is
>   being highlighted by calling highlightRow(sectionID, rowID). This sets
>   a boolean value of adjacentRowHighlighted in renderSeparator, allowing
>   you to control the separators above and below the highlighted row. The
>   highlighted state of a row can be reset by calling highlightRow(null).

Another option is using open source modules built by the community.
The one closest to your needs I could find is : https://github.com/jaysoo/react-native-menu